# Vulkan. VkInstance and VkDevice not destroyed correctly

Tags: c++, vulkan

**Hello everyone.**

I've got a problem here.

In *Vulkan 1.2* when calling `vkDestroyInstance` the either `VK_LAYER_KHRONOS_validation` or `VK_LAYER_LUNARG_standard_validation` layers give me the following *[annoying]* output:

```
UNASSIGNED-ObjectTracker-ObjectLeak(ERROR / SPEC): msgNum: 0 - OBJ ERROR :
VK_DEBUG_REPORT_OBJECT_TYPE_DEVICE_EXT object VkDevice 0x215e63ab750[] has not been destroyed.
```

and

```
VUID-vkDestroyInstance-instance-00629(ERROR / SPEC): msgNum: 0 - OBJ ERROR :
For VkInstance 0x215e5fd6dd0[], VkSurfaceKHR 0x2aefa40000000001[] has not been destroyed.
```

*and so far and so forth.*

The point is: **I do destroy VkSurfaceKHR prior to destroying the instance** and also I **do destroy the device**.

```
XISCALL Win32VkContext::~Win32VkContext() 
{
    ...
    vkDestroyInstance(mVkInstance, nullptr);
    ... // some non-vulkan code
}
```

```
XResult XISCALL Win32VkContext::Terminate() noexcept
{
    ...
    vkDestroySurfaceKHR(mVkInstance, mVkSurface, nullptr);
    ...
    if (mVkDevice != VK_NULL_HANDLE) {
        vkDeviceWaitIdle(mVkDevice);
        vkDestroyDevice(mVkDevice, nullptr);
    }
    ...
}
```

The `Terminate` function **gets called**(*debugger can't lie=)*) from outside layer a lot before the
destructor...

If this is not a Vulkan bug so what can this be? I've googled like a lot but could not find anything what could've solved this issue...

Placing the `vkDestroyInstance` to the end of the `Terminate` function gives same results. Putting the thread to sleep also didn't help.

**UPD**: I thought it can also be the driver bug.

Comment: Don't add "solved" to the title. Press the green checkmark to the left of your answer to mark the problem as solved.

Comment: Came upon a similar issue of a device not being destroyed and found out it was caused by me destroying the instance before the device. Swapping the order got rid of the error.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to this question. The case was that the XVK_ASSERT macro did create 2 instances of instance and device...